# Angular Migration Error for Version 13.0.3

Tags: angular

I got the following issue while upgrading from Angular 12 to 13.0.3.

```
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 79 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular-devkit/build-angular @ "13.0.3" (was "12.2.13")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/cli @ "13.0.3" (was "12.2.13")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/compiler-cli @ "13.0.2" (was "12.2.13")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/language-service @ "13.0.2" (was "12.2.13")...
    Updating package.json with dependency typescript @ "4.4.4" (was "4.3.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/animations @ "13.0.2" (was "12.2.13")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/common @ "13.0.2" (was "12.2.13")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/compiler @ "13.0.2" (was "12.2.13")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/core @ "13.0.2" (was "12.2.13")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/forms @ "13.0.2" (was "12.2.13")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/localize @ "13.0.2" (was "12.2.13")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/platform-browser @ "13.0.2" (was "12.2.13")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/platform-browser-dynamic @ "13.0.2" (was "12.2.13")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/router @ "13.0.2" (was "12.2.13")...
  UPDATE package.json (5301 bytes)
✔ Packages successfully installed.
** Executing migrations of package '@angular/cli' **

...

> Migrates `[routerLink]=""` in templates to `[routerLink]="[]"` because these links are likely intended to route to the current page with updated fragment/query params.
× Migration failed: Cannot read property 'readWorkspace' of undefined
  See "C:\Users\BENEDI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-0SNaUB\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

The angular-errors.log content is simply this:

```
[error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'readWorkspace' of undefined
    at C:\angular_upgrade\Nova\Avatar\node_modules\@angular\core\schematics\utils\project_tsconfig_paths.js:117:59
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\angular_upgrade\Nova\Avatar\node_modules\@angular\core\schematics\utils\project_tsconfig_paths.js:14:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\angular_upgrade\Nova\Avatar\node_modules\@angular\core\schematics\utils\project_tsconfig_paths.js:10:12)
    at getWorkspace (C:\angular_upgrade\Nova\Avatar\node_modules\@angular\core\schematics\utils\project_tsconfig_paths.js:115:16)
    at C:\angular_upgrade\Nova\Avatar\node_modules\@angular\core\schematics\utils\project_tsconfig_paths.js:40:37
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\angular_upgrade\Nova\Avatar\node_modules\@angular\core\schematics\utils\project_tsconfig_paths.js:14:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

Has anyone encountered this and how do you fix it?

Rgds,
Benedict

Comment: I assume `readWorkspace` is in *your* code, right? What if you comment it out and rerun migration?

Answer (score 1):

This should work after installing from npm using migrate-only.

```
 ng update --migrate-only --from=12 --to=13 @angular/core
```

Answer (score 1):

try this!

```
npm i @angular-devkit/core@13 --save
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the following steps helped:

1. Go back to angular 12 version - reset your git back to where you were before the updated begun.
2. Install package `angular-devkit/core`. Because it exports that missing function `readWorkspace`.

   1. `npm i angular-devkit/core --save-dev`
3. Repeat the upgrade

   1. `npx @angular/cli@13 update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13`

Answer (score 0):

Try updating `Angular 12` to `Angular 13` like this below:

```
ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@13 --force
```